# Does an evaluation function for a chess game consider all pieces on the board?

Tags: java, chess, minimax, evaluation-function

I hope this is an easily answered question, but I am slightly confused about how an evaluation function for a chess game works. I am using a minimax algorithm that evaluates the board at the leaf nodes, taking into account material, piece-square tables, mobility, etc. Does an evaluation function for a minimax algorithm (not negamax) take into account every piece on the board, both black and white, to calculate a board value or does it just look at the pieces of the minimser(black) or maximiser(white).

For instance, do I sum the material of both black and white or just whichever side's turn it is when the evaluate_board() method is called?

I apologise if this is confusing, but I am new to this. Even a little bit of clarification would be much appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: If you haven't visited https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/ before, you can find *lots* of information there. (Probably too much :-).

Comment: I don't write these kinds of programs, but I would assume that the evaluation method could be as simple or as complex as you desire and need. I  would imagine that the very good ones would evaluate all positions, that the better programs would allow for flexible degree of depth of evaluation...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a true programming question though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evaluation of a position can take **anything into account**. If you use minimax, you might want negative scores to be good for white and postive for black -- or something like that. So if you only use **material** to evaluate, you could count each white piece as `-N` and each black piece as `+N`. And the starting position is 0.

Keep in mind that even with pruning, minimax can take a long time if you go even a few ply (depths). So the *cheaper* or faster the evaluation method is, the better. Simple material advantage IMHO is the only evaluation you'll need.

Of course the chess wiki has a thorough article on the evaluation part of a chess engine: https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Evaluation